# GNU Screen: new window name change

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, window-title

I can change the name of a window with Ctrl-a Shift-a. Instead of editing several window names by hand, is there a way to have them automatically named after the current directory?

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: I'm using bash.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make your shell change the window title every time it changes directory, or every time it displays a prompt.

For your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [[ "$TERM" == screen* ]]; then
  screen_set_window_title () {
    local HPWD="$PWD"
    case $HPWD in
      $HOME) HPWD="~";;
      $HOME/*) HPWD="~${HPWD#$HOME}";;
    esac
    printf '\ek%s\e\\' "$HPWD"
  }
  PROMPT_COMMAND="screen_set_window_title; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
fi
```

Or for your `~/.zshrc` (for zsh users):

```
precmd () {
  local tmp='%~'
  local HPWD=${(%)tmp}
  if [[ $TERM == screen* ]]; then
    printf '\ek%s\e\\' $HPWD
  fi
}
```

For more information, look up under [Dynamic titles](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Dynamic-Titles) in the Screen manual, or under “Titles (naming windows)” in the man page.

Comment: I copypasted the bash one on my .bashrc and it is giving off these errors: bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 0: `;screen_set_window_title'

Comment: @David: Sorry, the point was to accumulate commands in `PROMPT_COMMAND` if there was already something, but I had the components in the wrong order.

Comment: Great trick @Gilles. For those who like to keep window titles short, you can drop the full path and only keep the basename. Just replace `$HOME/*) HPWD="~${HPWD#$HOME}";;` with `*) HPWD=\`basename "$HPWD"\`;;`

Answer (score 0):

You can put this into the .bashrc to change the terminal name (window name) to the last directory (or file name) that you are in (working on).

`case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"'
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac`

more described here: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-bash-script)